# Second unwanted call made to browser history in JS

Tags: javascript, url, browser-history

In my application, I need to redirect using `browserHistory` created from [this package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/history). In order to pass some context, I need to add a query string to the URL. The format in which I receive these params is in JSON. So before being able to call `history.push`, I first need to stringify and encode the given JSON.

Here's an example:

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

const browserHistory = createBrowserHistory({ window });

const given = { x: 1 };

browserHistory.push(`/foo?test-param=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(given))}`);
```

This redirection works...BUT it breaks the native browser back button (sort of). You see what happens is that `encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(given))` outputs `%7B%22x%22%3A1%7D`. As soon as the browser sees the `%3A` part, it automatically changes it into a `:` in the URL bar. This causes an additional change in the `browserHistory`, meaning that two URL changes happened:

1. `/foo?test-param=%7B%22x%22%3A1%7D` which is the wanted outcome generated by the above code
2. `/foo?test-param=%7B%22x%22:1%7D` which is automatically done by the browser (decoding `%3A`)

The issue now is that when I press the browser's back button, it tries to go to the second last URL which is the one given in step 1 above and not the original referrer URL. This then re-triggers a conversion to step 2. So the only way to get back to the referral URL is to hit the back button 2 times in quick succession.

Has anybody encountered this before?

*PS: If I opt for `encodeURI` instead of `encodeURIComponent` above, it works. The reason for this is that `encodeURI` does not encode `:` to begin with.*

Comment: You could maybe use `atob` and `btoa` instead of `encodeURIComponent`

Comment: Thanks Keith. Has this not been deprecated? At least this is what my VSCode suggested when trying to use either.

Comment: No it' snot deprecated, you might have Node's typing installed instead of the browser.  ps, you could do `window.atob()` will help TS know it browser..

Comment: I tried btoa now. It seems to have the same result, only this time it happens to the = sign at the end of the Base64 string instead of the %3A. So In short the = gets re-rendered as %3D

Comment: Does this url with JSON need to be bookmarked?, as the history api has a better place to put JSON type data when using history api..   If you can't use the history api data, and you have to use the url, you could try using Hex instead, but you will need a couple of utility functions to do the hex..

Comment: It will be used from within emails. So I don't think we would be able to rely on state.

Answer (score 0):

If this is going in Emails, and the URL want to have JSON embeded somehow, I would use Hex.  This should avoid any conflicts with special chars..

eg..

```js
const given = { x: 1 };

const toHex = s => [...new TextEncoder().encode(s)].map(m => m.toString(16)).join('');

const fromHex = h => 
  (new TextDecoder()).decode(
  new Uint8Array(
  h.match(/.{1,2}/g).map(v => parseInt(v, 16)))); 

const url = `/foo?testparam=${toHex(JSON.stringify(given))}`;

console.log(url);
console.log(JSON.parse(fromHex('7b2278223a317d')));
```